# Do sound waves cause pressure if so how much?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, estimation

Can sound waves cause extreme pressure? How hard would it be to cause said pressure?

Comment: Sound waves are pressure waves in one way.

Comment: Have a look at this link which gives you some indication of the magnitude of the variation in pressure due to a sound wave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure

Answer (score 1):

Sound waves are pressure waves: what your ears sense are the fluctuations of the pressure. One can become deaf after hearing a too intense sound (for example in a concert, or after shooting without protections), which is caused by a pressure so strong that can damage the eardrum. Causing this extreme pressure is then not that hard: using powerful speakers, or even bangers can be enough. As an aside, the Tsar Bomba (the most powerful bomb ever created, around 50Mt) is said to have broken window panes more than 500 miles away from where it exploded.